# Does java GC take into account references made in another thread?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, garbage-collection

Suppose a local variable is defined, then passed into a Thread constructor, where it's saved as a private field of that thread. Then, the thread gets kicked off to run continuously (forever, essentially), while the original method ends.

The local variable reference is gone, but does GC take into account the reference stored by the Thread object?

My scenario is similar to this example snippet:

```
...

public static void Main(String... args) {
  Foo foo = new Foo()
  MyThread thread = new MyThread(foo)
  ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
  executor.execute(thread)
}

...

public class MyThread implements Runnable {

  private Foo foo;

  public MyThread(Foo foo) {
     this.foo = foo;
  }

  public void run() {
     while (true) {
         this.foo.print(); // << throws NullPointerException
         sleep(...)
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Put this into a debugger, and then look at the object reference id. You'll see the same id in use. So, the object `Foo` will not be GC'd as it is still in use.

Comment: This code doesn't even compile. I fixed the syntax errors and ran it, but it did not throw a `NullPointerException`. Please provide a minimal, verifiable and complete example, so that we can run it and reproduce your error.

Comment: Maybe it has more to do with Main() exiting before the thread executes.  So the local thread object goes away, deleting everything else.  I haven't used ExecutorService, but I imagine that there is some method to wait for the thread to complete running before exiting Main()

Comment: @marstran Sorry about that, the code I'm working with has a bunch of other jargon with it so I tried simplifying it.

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe that the GC would not take it into account? Did you run into a problem and you thought that it could perhaps be explained if the GC didn't do that? Otherwise it sounds like a strange question - why would it not take that reference into account, as any page or book on the Java GC explains that it takes all references into account?

Comment: I tried running a simplified example as well and it did not throw a NullPointerException. Is there any other ways besides GC that a object can become null asides from assigning the reference to null?

Comment: @erwinBolwidt I have suspicions of GC because I ran into a similar problem a long time ago, although that one had something to do with GC cleaning up a open file object. I'm also looking into the possibility of GC causing problems because the part of code I'm dealing with is very small, and I'm positive I'm not accidentally assigning the field to null, or passing in a null object.

Comment: Ran another experiment with the actual code in question by keeping track of the variable in the parent class. Can confirm it's not GC (or at least not in the way I've posed it in the question). I'll post more once I figure out where the problem is coming from. Thanks for the suggestions everyone

Comment: I can assure you that the GC won't let you reference objects after they've been cleaned, unless you are using a `WeakReference` or a `SoftReference`. This is most likely a programming error on your part.

Comment: Also, when you simplify the code to put it in a question: Make sure it compiles, and that it still gives the same error when you run it. Otherwise it's impossible to find the error for us.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Briefly, yes, the *GC* does take into account the reference stored in `MyThread` class and won't delete the referenced object.** This is due to the fact that Java's garbage collector will only destroy unreachable objects, that is, objects that are not being referenced anywhere in your code (not exactly a general rule, take a look at [weak references](https://web.archive.org/web/20061130103858/http://weblogs.java.net/blog/enicholas/archive/2006/05/understanding_w.html)).

The variable `foo` is not an actual object, but rather a reference to one. When you pass `foo` to `MyThread`'s constructor you are not passing the object, but a reference to it. Inside the constructor, you are copyng this reference and storing it inside a member variable of `MyThread`. Since the `run()` method of that class will run "forever" (meaning that an instance of `MyThread` is "alive"), the reference in question will live "forever", thus preventing the referenced object from being garbage collected.

Note that `MyThread`'s name is wrong, so to speak. It doesn't extend `Thread` and, therefore, it's not a thread. It's simply an implementation of the `Runnable` interface. A more accurate name would be `MyRunnable`.

Comment: Actually, the garbage collector can garbage collect objects, even when in use, as long as it is possible to execute the code without the associated memory. But since this implies that there will be no behavioral change, it doesn’t matter. The more important (and simpler to understand) point is that the garbage collector will never set ordinary variables to `null`, so it can’t be the cause of the `NullPointerException`.